# Proof that the Killing form on a simple Lie algebra is non-degenerate

Tags: lie-algebras

This is obvious since there is a more general result for semi-simple Lie algebras, but I would like to prove it directly.

So suppose that the Killing form $\kappa$ is degenerate and let $X\in L$ be such that $\kappa(X,Y)=0$ for all $Y \in L$.

I would now like to use $X$ to construct a non-trivial ideal of $L$, thereby showing that it is not simple.

The ideal $\mathrm{span}_{\mathbb{F}}\{[X,Y] : Y \in L\} $ seems promising, but I haven't been able to show that it is non-trivial. I'm not sure if I am on the right track.

**UPDATE** Dietrich Burde's answer shows that this is in fact *not true* if for example the field $\mathbb{F}$ has characteristic 3. So in this case I assume I am only considering fields of characteristic 0, and moreover one may assume that $\kappa$ does not vanish identically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that the characteristic is zero. $I=\{X:K(X,.)=0\}$ is an ideal. To see this, note that $K([X,Y],Z)=K(X,[Y,Z])$. If $K(X,.)=0,$ for every $Y,Z$, $K([X,Y],Z)=K(X,[Y,Z])=0$. This implies that $[X,Y]\in I$. Suppose that $I$ is not $\{0\}$. Then, since the Lie algebra ${\cal G}$ is simple, $I={\cal G}$ and $K=0$. This implies that ${\cal G}$ is solvable by the Cartan criterion. Contradiction.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_criterion#Cartan.27s_criterion_for_solvability

Comment: Thank you. Our course did not cover solvability, but we were given the extra assumption that $\kappa$ does not vanish identically, so that allows us to exclude the case $I=G$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a counterexample. Consider the simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(3)/Z(\mathfrak{sl}(3))$ over a field of characteristic $p=3$. Then the Killing form is given by $$
\begin{pmatrix}
12 & -6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
-6 & 12 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which is identical zero for $3=0$.

Comment: I don't know what to say... this was an exam question: "Prove that, if g is
simple, then $\kappa$ is necessarily non-degenerate. [Here you may assume that $\kappa$ does not vanish identically.]"

Comment: For the exam question, probably, there was an assumption on the field $\mathbb{F}$. What did it say about the field?

Comment: There was no explicit mention of that, but the course only covered Lie algebras over fields of characteristic $0$. Actually, just $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I'm new to the subject. Could tell me why (or some hints) that $\mathfrak{sl}(3)/Z$ is simple (in my case s.s. will be enough), and if I'm right, $Z$ is all the scalar matrices, which is one dimensional, so the resulting quotient algebra will be 7 dimensional. But your matrix for the Killing form is 8 by 8. Did I miss something?